# Load webside in iOS App and Android App, not loading after changes

Tags: android, ios, laravel, web

I have a page that is opened inside a webview (Android) and uiwebview(iOS). When it is in the app, it works perfectly, but when I made a change in the code in the hosting site, the page wont't load in Android or iOS either. It's telling me that "error resource is not available". The page does load after refreshing many times. I don't know what is happening. The page is built in Laravel 5.1 and my hosting site is GoDaddy.

Does anyone has the same problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the app hosted on godaddy using javascript files? In that case you might want to handle that in android app. 
For starters you can try to access the website in chrome/ any browser on android device, if its working, try and delete data/cache of app from settings. Or simply just uninstall and install again.